# How does the change of sign convention effect a non-diagonal metric in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions, coordinate-systems

If we had the metric

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
t & a & b & c \\
a & -x& d & e \\
b & d & -y& f \\
c & e & f & -z \end{array} \right) $

What happens if we wanted to work with signs $(−+++)$ instead of $(+−−−)$?

Does only the sign of diagonal elements change?

Comment: No, you multiply the whole metric by $-1$

Answer (score 2):

In general, the *signature* of a metric is the number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues denoted $(p,q,r)$ respectively. I will work in $d = 2$ for simplicity, taking the metric to be,

$$g = \begin{pmatrix}
t & a\\ 
a & -x
\end{pmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalues are,

$$\lambda_\pm = \frac12 \left( t-x \pm \sqrt{4a^2 + (t+x)^2}\right).$$

For $t>0$ and $x,a \in \mathbb R$ the signature always remains the same, namely, $(1,1)$. If you switch the signs of the diagonal elements, the metric remains $(1,1)$ everywhere. You can generalise this for higher dimensions, and notice under certain conditions metrics can have different signatures for different regions of space-time.

You can read more about metrics with non-constant signature [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9610063). Note that in the context of general relativity, the signature does not affect the physics; pick $(3,1)$ or $(1,3)$.

Comment: I see where you went with this, but doesn't working in $d=2$ trivialize the problem to the point where it becomes useless? Obviously, in $d=2$, switching the signs of the diagonal elements will keep the signature the same. There's an equal number of positive and negative elements. To truly get the point you are making across, wouldn't $d=3$ be more effective?

Comment: Furthermore, the choice between mostly minus or mostly plus metric is up to the physicist because it doesn't change the actual physics. So, could you maybe add a blurb (for total completion's sake) answering the question of whether only the diagonals change sign or if other elements are affected as well in order to maintain the physical results while changing from mostly minus to mostly plus.

Comment: One last additional nitpick (and this one makes me feel kind of petty. I'm sorry). I have issues with the math you've posted (at least, in the way you posted it). Taking the signature and the eigenvalues as you defined them, it's pretty obvious that, for $t>0$ and $x,a\in\mathbb R$, there are valid values of $t$, $x$, and $a$ that result in signatures other than $(1,1,0)$. For instance, $a=0,x<0$ always results in a signature of $(2,0,0)$. Given that it's a continuous function (more or less), there must be points transitioning from $(1,1,0)$ to $(2,0,0)$ where you'd find $(1,0,1)$ like $x=a=0$

Comment: Sorry for the long rant. I know it makes it look like I dislike this answer. That is simply not true. I very much like the way this answer is presented and agree with the general message. I'm just trying to play devil's advocate and point out areas that others might take issue with. All this in the hopes that we (or, to give more specific credit where it's due: YOU) can hash out a complete and unassailable answer. You still get my +1  regardless

Comment: @Jim Firstly, yes, $d= 2$ somewhat trivialises the problem but I wrote this in the early hours of the morning after gym and didn't fancy doing the $d=3$ case. For completion's sake, I will add that the signature does not matter *in the context of general relativity*, since in string theory in defining the path integral for example, signature does matter due to constraints from geometry and topology on the metrics we can choose on surfaces. I will add further details tomorrow morning :)